# Convert Time with offset to UTC and return localdatetime

Tags: java, date, parsing, time, utc

I have a Method which parses a String according to Iso8601 and returns a LocalDateTime.
Now I accept possible offsets.
The Problem now is I have to convert the offset to UTC and return it as LocalDateTime.

So far I have tried working with Instant, OffsetDateTime, ZonedDateTime. 
I always get the opposite. Instead of +06:00 my result will be shown as -06:00.

`return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.from(OffsetDateTime.parse(date, buildIso8601Formatter())), ZoneOffset.UTC);`

This is the solution which works the same as my other tried ones I mentioned above.

I know this is not the common way to do it and I did a lot of research because of that but the current architecture only allows me to do it that way.

EDIT example:
With an implementation like this:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date, buildIso8601Formatter()); 
Instant instant = offsetDateTime.toInstant();


return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Let's say I get `"2020-01-12T08:30+06:00"` as input for my method. I HAVE to return LocalDateTime.

As a result I want to have `"2020-01-12T14:30"` instead my best solution was to get it the opposite way: `"2020-01-12T02:30"`.

Comment: What is the time you are trying to convert? Can you show it along with some tries that failed?

Comment: If you are dealing with offsets, why are you using `LocalDateTime` instead of (what would be correct) using `OffsetDateTime`?

Comment: @deHaar The time is a String which can have a format like this "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm+00:00".I updated the answer and hope this clarifies it.

Comment: What "rule" makes the timestamp `2020-01-12T08:30+06:00` correspond to `2020-01-12T14:30`? I ask because `08:30+06:00` is the same time as `02:30+00:00`!

Comment: According to offsets, `8:30 +6z` == `2:30 +0z` == `14:30 +12z` the zone part says "this is the time at utc + whatever the offset is"

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I'm not sure I understand your question properly. Besides my now edited example I have a formatter.

Comment: I wanted to tell you, that the resultig time that you want, does not correspond to the input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of `java.time` is correct. The string `2020-01-12T08:30+06:00` means that the datetime part of this string is a datetime *local* to some region, which exists in an area with an offset of `+06:00` from UTC.

Your interpretation is different from the abovementioned case. In your case, you interpret `08:30` as a time in sync with UTC, and then concatenate the timezone offset string for the desired region.

So if you really want to do this – think again.

---

One way to achieve this, is simply by parsing the datetime as an offset datetime and *negate* the offset.

Comment: I really had a wrong loop in my head thinking about this. The comments and your answer helped me a lot. I have to reconsider my decision now and know the way how to implement that.